# Image placement in HTML CSS

Tags: css, html

```css
body
{
background-image:url("images/Wheat.jpg");
}
p 
{
    font-family: "Sans-serif";
    font-size: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size:150%;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #000000;
}
{color:#996633;
font-family:Arial;
text-align: center; 
font-size: 200%;
}

h3
{
color:#996633;
font-family:Arial;
font-style: italic;
text-align:left;
font-size: 200%;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 


 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- specify link to external layout file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Testimonials.css"/>
<title>Sandwich Express</title>


</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">

<table img-src="images/sanex.jpg" width="100%" style="height: 50%;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>

<!--  HEADER SECTION -->
<td colspan="2" style="height: 80px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><h1><img src="CSS/images/sanex.jpg" alt="Sandwich Express" style="width:100%;height:150px"> </h1></td></tr>
<!--  NAVIGATION BAR SECTION  -->
<tr><b><td colspan="5" valign="middle" height="40" bgcolor="#ECE5B6"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></b></td></tr>

<tr>
<!-- LEFT COLUMN (MENU)  -->
<td width="10%" valign="top" bgcolor="#DEB887">
<a href="CSS/Menu.html">Menu</a><br>
<br></br>
<a href="CSS/Delivery.html">Delivery</a><br>
<br></br>
<a href="CSS/Testimonials.html">Testimonials</a><br>
<br></br>
<a href="CSS/Contact.html">Contact information</a><br>

</td>

<!-- top right column-->
<td img src="images/flower.jpg">
<h2>
<h2>Contact us</h2><br><br>

<h3>How to contact us? </h3>
<p>Please call us on 0000000000 </p>
<p> Or feel free to use our web-form</p>

 
 <form action="#" method="post">
  <p>
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input name="name" id="name" type="text" required/>
  </p>
  <p>
   <label for="email">E-mail</label>
   <input name="email" id="email" type="email" required/>
  </p>
  <p>
   <label for="Contact">Contact Number</label>
   <input name="website" id="website" type="url"/>
  </p>
  <p>
   <label for="Inquiry">Inquiry</label>
   <textarea name="comment" id="comment" required></textarea>
  </p>
  <p> <input type="submit" value="Post comment"/></p>
 </form>

<br>
<h3>Our address is</h3>
<p>Sandwich Express</p>
<p>Some Back Alley</p>
<p>Middle of Lincoln</p>
<p>Great Britian</p>

<tr><td colspan="2"  height="20" bgcolor="#ECE5B6">Copyright Keeley Wainman, University of Lincoln ©</td></tr></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
 <body>
 <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
  background-color: #CCC;
        position: bottom; 
   }
</style>
</body>
</table>
</body>
```

Hey, so after I've finally got something going I've gone to place a google map (not fully implemented yet), just trying to get the right placement for it. It seems tho I can't get the google map to move to the bottom of the page where I'd like it? Or even how do I get the image to move? It seems to have gone above the border at the top, this is really poor positioning and I have to move it to the bottom. Any help to whats going wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dumping all of your code in the question isn't helpful.

Comment: I apologise but I don't know where in the code I'm having the issue.

Comment: Then you should find out. Start removing unrelated parts until the problem disappears. Shrink your problem to a minimal test case, and read the article I linked.

Comment: @KeeleyLouiseWainman no offense to you, but it's probably better if you design your website and code it without using <table> around the whole body, it's generally better to just use the basic setup of <body> <header> <article> and <footer> a few years back a lot of people used tables to create their websites, but this has a few flaws..if you're interested in more information: http://blog.silktide.com/2011/04/why-you-shouldnt-use-tables-for-layout-ever/ P.S: if you change your website and remove said table, your map will go to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
        <tr><td><div id="map-canvas"></div></td></tr>
```

at the end of your page, instead of:

```
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

it will place your map at the bottom of the page, it was at the top because you didn't assign a `<tr>` and `<td>` to it

good luck coding! ^^

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/h261cgc9/ Here's a fiddle to see the change i've made in action

But as I've mentioned in my comment, it's much better to create a website without the use of tables, only use tables when you actually want to put something in one, putting a whole body in the table is a bad idea, see: http://blog.silktide.com/2011/04/why-you-shouldnt-use-tables-for-layout-ever/

In the fiddle I removed the  which contained the styles, as there is no need for it, you could just put the styles at the top of the page in between the `<head>` and `<body>`